# Simulating pneumatic tools/devices?

Tags: pressure, air

I need to simulate an air compressor/pneumatic system for a train simulator. How do I find the pressure of an air tank after lots of things have used small portions of the compressed air?

For example, the horn on the train. I read that the horn typically runs at 100psi, but the main reservoir is kept at 130-140psi. I assume there's a simple pressure regulator for the horn, but how would I find the pressure in the reservoir after the horn has been running for a known amount of time?

Comment: You need a model for the flow rate trough the horn as a function of pressure and then you can solve a differential equation. If the flow rate is proportional to the pressure difference to the atmosphere, then this differential equation is linear and the solution will be an exponential function.

Comment: Okay, well after further digging I found that the horn runs at 70cfm. Edit: I can't get this link thing to work on my phone, I'll post later from a computer when I'm home. Sorry

Comment: @K4KFH That's 70cfm - at some fixed pressure; perhaps the setpoint of the regulator you mention - if there is one. But without a fixed inlet pressure the flow rate can vary. And for an orifice-like device the pressure flow relationship is usually not linear but more likely quadratic. And with a regulator, and depending on the quality of the regulator and how much accuracy is required for your model, you may need to consider droop. In other words the regulated pressure may deviate from the setpoint depending on flow rate through the regulator.

Comment: @K4KFH  ... and furthermore getting back to CuriousOne's comments you start with a model and if you can settle for a linear approximation your differential equations will be nonlinear. And I know from experience the quadratic behavior I mentioned will not allow a closed form solution so if you need this degree of fidelity you will have to settle for numerical solutions or simulation results.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear above, the horn uses 70cfm @ 100psi. I'm not sure I need to account for tiny imperfections in pressure due to quality of the regulator; that seems over the top for what I'm doing. I want this to be accurate, but there's a point at which I am willing to say "it is JUST a game"

Comment: See this post for how I'm planning to do it: http://linux-networking-and-puns.tumblr.com/post/136516891208/modeling-pneumatic-systems-with-pressure